# Removing class from html

Tags: html, css

How can i remove my image 11 from class second?

```
<ul class="second">
    <li >
        <a href="#"><img class="imgTwo" src="img/11.gif"></a>
        <a href="#"><h4>9</h4></a>
        <a href="#"><h5>9.1</h5></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="imgTwo" src="img/12.gif"></a>
        <a href="#"><h4>10</h4></a>
        <a href="#"><h5>10.1</h5></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want to remove the tag? or just hide the image?

Comment: ive given animation to this class second and i dont want to include image 11 in it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this way:

```
ul.second > li:first-child .imgTwo {
  display: none;
}
```

This way only the first one will be deleted.